# DynamoDB counter field statistics only per last N days

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I have a DynamoDB table with two fields: entityID (hash key) and clickedCounter. clickedCounter is an auto incremented counter that counts how many times user clicked on entityID, I marked clickedCounter as a DynamoDB version attribute (with java annotation DynamoDBVersionAttribute).
With such table I could easily get statistics how many times each entityID were clicked for all the time, but I need **to get summarized statistics only per last N days** (for example, per last 7 days). How can I archive this?

As a potential solution, I can add two more fields: expiredTime (actually it’s a time to live attribute, so the old data will be removed automatically) and dayOfYear. Here dayOfYear is a hash key and entityID is a range key. For example, for the 10th of January, app will store the following data for entityID equals to 1005 for only last 3 days (and data for previous days will be removed by TTL manager):

```
 dayOfYear   entityID  clickedCounter  expiredTime 
 10          1005      9                …
 9           1005      10               …                     
 8           1005      19               …                 
 7           1005      12               …
```

To get statistics for example above, I should do load request by hash and range key pairs (in this example, by pairs <10, 1005>,   <9, 1005>, <8, 1005>, <7, 1005>) and sum all clickedCounter values (here sum is 50) .

Is it possible to get summarized statistics only per last N days in a simpler and more correct way?

Comment: I wouldn't event have 'clickedCounter', instead entityID (hashkey), clickedTimestamp (sortkey). Whenever you want to get total, get ScannedCount like described here. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Query.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DynamoDB is designed to provide fast lookup in massive scale, and not as an analytical DB. It is better to use an analytical tool for analytical queries. You might be able to create a better counter for such an aggregation, but then you would like to have another calculation such as average or a different time window, and your counter will not be useful for it.

I would capture the changes to the DynamoDB table, using [DynamoDB stream](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Streams.html), and record these changes into an analytical data store, such as Redshift or simply into S3 (using [Kinesis Firehose](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/firehose/latest/dev/create-destination.html#create-destination-s3), for example). Once you have that log changes in that analytical data store, you can run flexible queries on it. For example, you can use [Athena](https://aws.amazon.com/athena/) (or any other SQL on S3 tool) to query your data in S3.

Answer (score 0):

DynamoDB has no native support for analytical queries. One way to do this though is to use integration with [EMR Hive](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/EMRforDynamoDB.Tutorial.html) or [Redshift](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/RedshiftforDynamoDB.html). You can either export data from DynamoDB into one of these systems and perform queries on this snapshot, or with EMR Hive you can run queries on DynamoDB data. In any case you will be able to run arbitrary SQL queries on your data.

Keep in mind that no matter what tool you use it will read all data in your table, so it will be either expensive (you need to provision a lot of RCUs/WCUs) or slow, so you won't be able to run these queries interactively.

Another option, as @Guy suggested is to maintain an aggregated table with DynamoDB stream and Lambda. This will work much faster and will be way cheaper, but it's much less flexible, since you may end up maintaining a separate table for each query you need to make.